# Can't filter on category in loop when using Custom Post Type in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to display posts from a custom post type called portfolio using the code below and then filter the result by category, I have tried putting - category_name , catid, portfolio_category in the array

and have had a look around the forums and tried a few things but cant seem to get it to work , it either displays nothing or all the post from all categories.

```
     <?php
     $args=array(
    'post_type' => 'portfolio',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 7,
    'caller_get_posts'=> 1
     );
     $my_query = null;
     $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
     if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
     while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
     <p><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to 
     <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
     <?php
      endwhile;
      }
     wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post().
     ?>
```

The registered taxonomy is portfolio_category, any help on this would be appreciated , many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to call the the category as a custom taxonomy:

```
'portfolio_cat' => 'name_of_your_category'
```

Comment: this is how I have got it to work $args = array(
        'post_type'=>'portfolio',
 'tax_query' => array(
  array(
   'taxonomy' => 'portfolio_category',
   'field' => 'slug',
   'terms' => 'solutions'
  )
 )
);
$my_query = new WP_Query( $args );

Comment: @Ledgemonkey You're welcome. You could have marked my answer as accepted since it was right. At least vote for it. Anything but not a negative reputation. :(

Answer (score 1):

After trying a few things this is how i got it to work using the 'tax_query' hope this helps someone...

```
     <?php

     $args = array(
     'post_type'=>'portfolio',
  'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'portfolio_category',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => 'solutions'
    )
   )
       );
     $my_query = new WP_Query( $args );

     if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
     while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>

     <p><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to 
     <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
     <?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
      <?php the_excerpt()?>
      <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID,  array(50,50)); ?> 
      <?php
      endwhile;
      }
     wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post().
     ?>
```